# Как мне получить весь список

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно получить из сайта список всех серий сериала
Используя код ниже

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll('.cdn_download_item span')[0];
a.innerText;
```

Я получаю только

```
'9 серия'
```

Мне нужно получить такой список

```
'9 серия'
'8 серия'
'7 серия'
'6 серия'
'5 серия'
'4 серия'
'3 серия'
'2 серия'
'1 серия'
```

Вот как все построено на сайте

```
<div class="box box_cdn_download" style="padding: 10px 0px; display: block;">
<b class="cdn_download_season">1 сезон</b>
<div class="cdn_download_item">
<span>9 серия</span>
<span style="text-transform: uppercase;">webdl</span>
 <span>Профессиональный (многоголосый закадровый) (LostFilm)</span>
<span>(2 Gb)</span>
<span>(1 Gb)</span>
<span>(461 Mb)</span>
<span>(244 Mb)</span>
<span>(143 Mb)</span>
</div>
<div class="cdn_download_item">
<span>8 серия</span>
<span style="text-transform: uppercase;">webdl</span>
 <span>Профессиональный (многоголосый закадровый) (LostFilm)</span>
<span>(2 Gb)</span>
<span>(1 Gb)</span>
<span>(461 Mb)</span>
<span>(244 Mb)</span>
<span>(143 Mb)</span>
</div>
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: var a = document.querySelectorAll('.cdn_download_item span')[0]; Так вы берете только элемент с нулевым индексом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.cdn_download_item span:first-child'));

for (element of elements) {
  console.log(element.innerText);
}
```

```html
<div class="box box_cdn_download" style="padding: 10px 0px; display: block;">
  <b class="cdn_download_season">1 сезон</b>
  <div class="cdn_download_item">
    <span>9 серия</span>
    <span style="text-transform: uppercase;">webdl</span>
    <span>Профессиональный (многоголосый закадровый) (LostFilm)</span>
    <span>(2 Gb)</span>
    <span>(1 Gb)</span>
    <span>(461 Mb)</span>
    <span>(244 Mb)</span>
    <span>(143 Mb)</span>
  </div>
  <div class="cdn_download_item">
    <span>8 серия</span>
    <span style="text-transform: uppercase;">webdl</span>
    <span>Профессиональный (многоголосый закадровый) (LostFilm)</span>
    <span>(2 Gb)</span>
    <span>(1 Gb)</span>
    <span>(461 Mb)</span>
    <span>(244 Mb)</span>
    <span>(143 Mb)</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень Вам признателен за помощь

Comment: @VladYorkyee, лучше `.textContent`.

Comment: Алексей Шиманский, я добавил дополнение пожалуйста прочтите выше

Comment: @VladYorkyee  у массива есть метод push

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, переписал через push, да теперь данные записываются, но там идут масса дубликатов(всего получается 76 значений!), что я не так написал? посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: @VladYorkyee если у вас возник новый вопрос - задайте его на ruSO опубликовав новый вопрос с долнжым оформлением.